# ClearCase: how to change the master replica where the current replica is different?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I changed a master replica of a stream by mistake.
and when I wanted to recover the old master replica I got this error

```
cleartool chmaster rep1@\pVob_aff stream:grWork@\pVob_aff


cleartool: Error: Unable to perform operation "change master" in replica "rep1" of VOB 
"\pVob_aff".
cleartool: Error: Master replica of activity "grWork" is "rep2".
```

is there a way to change the current replica "rep1" to "rep2" in order to change the master replica of the stream and then turn it back to "rep1" ?

because now I can't do checkouts in this stream

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have a stream named `grWork`, and an activity named `grWork`.

You could try the `chmaster` first on the activity, before trying it on the stream.

```
cleartool chmaster rep1@\pVob_AFFAIRES_SPOCC activity:grWork@\pVob_aff
```

Comment: I don't have an activity named grWork, i've an activity named "test" I try ur command and I got the same error  `Error: Master replica of activity "test" is "rep2"` (because the master replica of my activity is also rep2)

Comment: @Agnes OK: `activity "grWork"` seems misleading then.

Comment: @Agnes Would using [`multitool chmaster`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chmaster.htm) work better in your case?

Comment: @Agnes At least a `multitool chmaster -all rep2@\pVob_AFFAIRES_SPOCC rep1@\pVob_AFFAIRES_SPOCC`

Comment: the multitool command is not recognized in my envirnnmeent

Comment: @Agnes Strange, considering the error message is about "replica", a ClearCase multi-site notion usually managed by `multitool`.

Comment: The chmaster command listed will not work. The chmaster -all command would have to be run at rep2 to send mastership.of everything to rep1? Also, DONT DO THAT.

Comment: @BrianCowan Great, I was waiting for you to chime in. I will delete my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you.running the chmaster at "rep2"? Are the replicas in sync? Mastership changes on streams can only be done at the site that masters the stream. You cannot reqmaster a stream.

With respect to the error message, in a schema 54.VOB, just about every UCM object shares the same "ClearGuide Activity" namespace, which is why folder, project, stream, baseline, AND activity names have to be globally unique... (projects can't have the same name as a folder/stream/etc.). As such, its possible that you're looking at a legacy error message.